# Angularjs directive live binding between variable and css property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I would like to live update a div element css property (min-height) in the HTML, if I change a controller variable (the variable contains the height in px, lets say 445).

The problem is, the variable in the directive is always undefined.
I tried with $watch also, but still does not work.

Here is a jsfiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/xs0upf20/

Here is the sourcecode:

```
<div ng-app="ctrl">
  <div ng-controller="TempCtrl">
    <span temp-directive>here we go</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('ctrl', []).controller('TempCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
         $scope.sideheight = 445;
     });

     angular.module('ctrl').directive('tempDirective', function () {
         return {
             restrict: 'A',
             scope: {
                 sideheight: '=sideheight'
             },
             link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                 console.log('outside watch');
                 console.log(scope.sideheight);
                 element.css('min-height', scope.sideheight+'px');
                 scope.$watch("onlyvariable", function(newValue,oldValue,scope){
                     console.log('inside watch');
                     console.log(scope);
                 });

             }
         };
     });
```

The `sideheight` variable is initialized with a default value (what I can not access already), and later if I change the variable I would like to see the css property updated.

I also tried '=', '@' binding, still no success. 
With @ binding, the variable is not even created in scope object, with = char, it has an undefined value. 
The $parent object does contain the sideheight variable, with the correct 445 value.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the sideheight from the controller into the directive, like so:

```
<div ng-app="ctrl">  
    <div ng-controller="TempCtrl">
        <span temp-directive sideheight="sideheight">here we go</span>
    </div>      
</div>
```

The directive's scope does not inherit sideheight from the controller, you must tell the directive what property or value on the controller the sideheight property takes.